# mysql query dont gets all posts

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL query who have to list all post i want it to post. But it dont do it. It shows posts when i have more then one post in the table "meaOrder" with the same "ordCode". But when i have only on post in meaOrder, i don't show it. What can i do?

```
SELECT koden, wish, rnamn, bild, pris, cname, onsktext 
                FROM (
                SELECT m.wishText as onsktext, m.meaOID as midn, m.ordcode as koden, w.wish as wish, r.meaName as rnamn, r.meaImg as bild, 
                        r.meaPrice as pris, k.catName as cname from cats k, meals r, wishes w,
                        meaOrder m
                    join orders c on c.ordNR=4401
                    WHERE  c.ordStatus=1 AND m.ordNR=c.ordNR AND m.meaID=r.meaID AND m.wishesID=w.id
                        AND r.catID=k.catID
                ) T
                GROUP BY koden, rnamn, bild, pris, cname
                ORDER BY midn DESC
```

TABLE orders
http://grab.by/m74E

TABLE meaOrder http://grab.by/m74Q

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: You appear to have a constant in the ON clause, and then the columns to check in the WHERE clause

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the JOIN with RIGHT JOIN in this case. The difference is explained at [JOIN Syntax page in MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) . In short - JOIN returns row only if there are corresponding rows in both joined tables (inner join). LEFT JOIN / RIGHT JOIN return all rows from one of the tables and corresponding row **if it exists** from the other table (those are outer joins)

Comment: It did'nt worked. I changed it to RIGHT JOIN but nothing happend.

Comment: As Kickstart said - you have ` on c.ordNR=4401 ` in ON clause. Move this condition to where clause and move `m.ordNR=c.ordNR` from WHERE clause to ON clause. 
Anyway, as Kickstart suggested before, it'd be a good idea to rewrite the query to use INNER/OUTER JOINS and ***NOT*** CROSS JOINS as it does now (specifying a list of coma-separated tables selects all combinations of rows from all those tables before the WHERE clause takes effect)

Comment: It did'nt worked, i tried very much ways, but it never worked. @jderda

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a subselect?

This seems to cover it:-

```
SELECT m.ordcode AS koden, w.wish AS wish, r.meaName AS rnamn, r.meaImg AS bild, r.meaPrice AS pris, k.catName AS cname, m.wishText AS onsktext 
FROM cats k 
INNER JOIN meals r ON r.catID = k.catID
INNER JOIN meaOrder m ON m.meaID = r.meaID 
INNER JOIN wishes w ON m.wishesID = w.id
INNER JOIN orders c ON m.ordNR = c.ordNR
WHERE  c.ordStatus = 1  
AND c.ordNR = 4401
GROUP BY m.ordcode, r.meaName, r.meaImg, r.meaPrice, k.catName
ORDER BY midn DESC
```